# DynamoDB: How to append to list values in document

Tags: javascript, node.js, lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB table, users, that has a document structure similar to the following:

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "john",
  "hobbies": [
    {
      "description": "painting",
      "skill": "amateur"
    },
    {
      "description": "cooking",
      "skill": "expert"
    }
  ]
}
```

As can be seen, the document structure contains a list attribute, hobbies, that can contain a collection of hobby "objects".

I want to write an update statement to add a new element to the list attribute if it doesn't exist yet.

For example, I want to be able to pass a hobby with a "description" of "designing" and a "skill" of "amateur" to my update function and, since this hobby isn't yet in the list of hobbies, it should be added to the list. If the hobby is already there, it should not be added a second time.

I am working in Node.js and therefore using JavaScript and the AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient() with a parameter map to perform my functions. The [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/gettingstartedguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.03.html) has been helpful, but I am struggling to find examples of how to set up params to conditionally append items to a list attribute as I am describing. Does anyone perhaps have some advice on how to do this?

Answer (score 11):

You can use [`list_append()` and `if_not_exists()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.Modifying.html#Expressions.Modifying.UpdateExpressions.SET.Functions) together in an [UpdateExpression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.Modifying.html#Expressions.Modifying.UpdateExpressions) to append to a potentially non-existent list column, but there is no way to prevent appending to that list if an object with the same properties already exists inside the list.

As an alternative you could replace your "hobbies" List with a String Set and just `JSON.stringify()` each "hobbie" before inserting it (and `JSON.parse()` it when reading the values back out):

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk')
var DB = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()
var hobbieToAdd = JSON.stringify({
  description: "designing",
  skill: "amateur"
})
DB.update({
  TableName: "TableName",
  Key: { id: "1" },
  UpdateExpression: "ADD #hobbies :hobbie",
  ExpressionAttributeNames: { "#hobbies" : "hobbies" },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: { ":hobbie": DB.createSet([hobbieToAdd]) }
})
```

Using a String Set would ensure that duplicates could never appear, but it also requires you to (de)serialize the hobbies yourself.

Comment: This is useful, thank you. The idea of a string set is something I could consider...the problem with this approach that (in a different use case I didn't mention in the question) the user will also be able to update one of their hobbies. For example, they might have a hobby of "painting" and which they are an "amateur", but after a while they might update their skill level for the "painting" hobby to "intermediate". And I think a string set will complicate this other use case.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, so to check for duplication in the array I need to do a `.get` at first, and then `update` the list? So It cannot be done inside only the update?